# Updating Shiro 1.2.6 to 1.3.0 breaks access to server side

Tags: shiro

In my application I updated only the Shiro library, from shiro-all-1.2.6.jar to shiro-all-1.3.0.jar. I did not change any other libraries, nor configuration files, other than the build path to refer to the new Shiro library.

The logs show that the users do actually get logged in, but the server side is not accessible anymore, right after shiro login.

Trying to figure out what changed between 1.2.6.and 1.3.0, and what settings do I need to change, to make the application work as before.

Thanks a bunch!
-Alina.

Comment: Hi @afrey!  Can you add more details to this post, the errors you are seeing in your logs, the response codes the server is returning.  What you mean by "build path" are you managing artifacts manually or via a build tool like Maven or Gradle?

SO has a great resource on how to ask better questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Building with ANT in Eclipse.

Comment: I was able to access the server side as soon as I modified the URLs in Shiro.ini to reflect path without the slash "/" at the beginning of the path:

[urls]

<web_app>/FileUploadServlet = authc
<web_app>/FileDownloadServlet = authc
<web_app>/UserUnloadServlet = authc
<web_app>/soa_service = authc
<web_app>/data_update = authc
<web_app>/data_view = authc
<web_app>/load_lists = authc
<web_app>/error_services = authc
<web_app>/query_db = authc
<web_app>.html = authc

Comment: Another discovery is that currentUser.isAuthenticated() returns TRUE with Shiro 1.2.6 and FALSE with Shiro 1.3.0. That's why my application was not loading. This is the code used for that:

Subject currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
if (currentUser.isAuthenticated()) {
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}

Also, currentUser.getPrincipal() returns null with shiro 1.3.0, while it returns the logged in user with shiro 1.2.6.

So, I have to figure out if I need to call the current user in a different way, or is there something that I need to change in my shiro.ini.

Comment: Have you tried turning up the logging for Shiro? ‘org.apache.shiro’. You can turn it up to TRACE if you need too.

Comment: Brian, thank you so much for all your help. It is greatly appreciated. 
I was not able to get any log messages displayed. I guess I don't know what I'm looking for. Are they supposed to be in the same file as the other log4j messages? I did not see any messages other than the ones coming from my log statements. But nothing from shiro. I don't even know what to look for. Where can I see some examples?

Comment: Per your recommendation, I have removed SLF4J-simple from my libraries folder and path, and modified the level for shiro stuff from DEBUG to TRACE.

Comment: log4j.properties:

`log4j.additivity.default=false
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.Name=ELELogger
log4j.appender.file.File=/home/oraweb/ele/log/DassleEleApp.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=25
log4j.appender.file.ImmediateFlush=true
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%-6p%d{DATE} - %C{1}.%M:%L - %m%n`

Comment: `log4j.logger.org.apache.shiro=TRACE
log4j.logger.org.apache.shiro.realm.text.PropertiesRealm=TRACE
log4j.logger.org.apache.shiro.cache.ehcache.EhCache=TRACE
log4j.logger.org.apache.shiro.io=TRACE
log4j.logger.org.apache.shiro.web.servlet=TRACE
log4j.logger.org.apache.shiro.util.ThreadContext=TRACE`

Comment: Both versions you mentioned are very old. You need to configure session storage, eg via a cache (single JVM app) or distributed (db, redis, etc). See https://shiro.apache.org/session-management.html#SessionManagement-SessionStorage for details.

Answer (score 0):

After more digging, I found out that the connection to the server was lost due to the fact that in the process, a new session is created, as the initial session is lost.

When calling `Session session = currentUser.getSession();`, I expect to get the same session associated with the logged-in user. Instead, a new session is created, because the old one does not persist.

Again, this is happening with Shiro 1.3.0, but not with Shiro 1.2.6.

I am wondering if there is a setting that we need to apply, for the session to persist, and not get lost. I wonder if the session times out instantly.